# fetch() api method POST sends to many data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, post, fetch

I have problem with sending data via POST method in fetch(). So the problem is that from this >> body: JSON.stringify({ id: uuid(), name, password }) it sends couple of times almost the same data (i receive unique id, and diplicated name and password). In the othet words: with one form submission, I've got few objects with differnt id, and same name and password. Code:

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    users.map(user =>
      user.name !== name && name.length >= 3 && password.length >= 5
        ? fetch('http://localhost:3003/users', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({ id: uuid(), name, password }),
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
          })
            .then(res => {
              if (res.ok) {
                return res.json();
              }
              throw new Error('Error');
            })
            .then(c => setUser([...users, c]))
            .then(errorUserChange(false))
        : errorUserChange(true)
    );
  };
```

db.json:

```
{
  "users": [

    {
      "id": "c1a10ab0-24c7-11ea-af77-3b28fe4ea407",
      "name": "cccccc",
      "password": "cccccc"
    },
    {
      "id": "cbf73890-24c7-11ea-af77-3b28fe4ea407",
      "name": "kkkkkkk",
      "password": "kkkkk"
    },
    {
      "id": "cbf786b0-24c7-11ea-af77-3b28fe4ea407",
      "name": "kkkkkkk",
      "password": "kkkkk"
    }
  ]
}
```

Of course I know that's not the best way to hold password, I'm just practicing json server and fetch().

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It looks like you are POSTing a list of users with `users.map(user => ...`. What are the contents of your `users` array?

Comment: yes, that was the problem; i've changed users.map(user =>... (third line), and works fine. Thanks anyway!